# Purpose of Error method in asp.net Core 2.0 MVC project template

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm new to asp.net Core 2.0.

When you Create a new ASP.net Core 2.0 MVC Project (Web Application (Model-View-Controller)), you get a HomeController with Index(), About() and Contact() methods as in MVC 5.

However you also get this:

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

I can't find any documentation in Google or in any books as to what this is for and what the purpose of the single line of code is.

Can somebody please explain it? Is it some kind of best practice - should we be using this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If time permit, I'll try to update my answer. But for now, the brief explanation is that every public method in your controller is callable as an http endpoint. For instance, the index method in your HomeController renders your index.cshtml view, the About renders the about.cshtml view and so on. In particular the public IActionResult Error() method is called if you redirect the user to the action when an error occurred. Consequently, it returns an Error View containing the information about the error, such as the RequestId and other values bonded with the ErrorViewModel.

I hope this help for now.

Comment: Are you sure? I've thrown an exception in an action method (throw new ArgumentException("a","b") - and the debugger never hits the Error() method.

Comment: Calling the Error() method is not automatic. One way to refer to it is by redirecting your user to the action when an error or exception occurred, using RedirectToAction("Error") call.